# Is there a way to serialize and resume async functions between interpreter restarts?

Tags: python, serialization, async-await

Say I have some async code like so:

```
    async def start(self):
        name = await self.text_prompt("Hi there! What's your name?")
        await self.send_message(f"Hello, {name}! How are you?")
        # --- crash ---
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await self.send_message("Lol")
```

I'm looking to make my runner code robust between interpreter crashes. In an ideal world, if the Python interpreter crashes right after the `send_message` and I restart it, I would be able to execute some magical series of steps such that the async routine here resumes right at the `# --- crash ---` point.

I could definitely make it work by changing how I write the code, for example if I re-wrote it like this:

```
    async def start(self):
        self.execute_steps([
            Step(self.text_prompt, "Hi there! What's your name?", store='name_response'),
            Step(self.send_message_name_response),
            Step(asyncio.sleep, 1),
            Step(self.send_message, "Lol"),            
        ])
```

Now I can serialize the Steps, my runner can keep track where it is, rebuild all needed data structures, etc.

My question is if this is possible just with the plain `async def` style?

Comment: What do you mean by _interpreter_ crashes? Something different from normal exceptions raised in code?

Comment: @kache: it can be a normal exception like keyboard interrupt from manually stopping it. So there’s time to do cleanup and store things etc